# How do multiple hubs work together with each other?

Tags: c#, signalr, signal-processing, signalr-hub, signalr.client

How do multiple hubs work together with each other?
How can I balance the hubs?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome.   Any code or research to show?  This will help us help you. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

SignalR uses the same connection to the server, however many hubs you are connected to.

> You can define multiple Hub classes in an application. When you do
>   that, the connection is shared but groups are separate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs